# How to logoff all users on windows from command line as a domain administrator

Tags: windows, command-line, continuous-integration

I'm running automation testing on Windows (windows 10 and 2012), and one of the requirements of the automation is that **ALL** users need to be logged off.  I have a chance to do this after deployment.  I kind of see [this page](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/2da3e724-eddf-4df7-8e0c-3fa545c2fec0/script-to-logoff-all-user-sessions-in-windows-2008-r2?forum=winserverTS) give an answer, but after I tried `query session`, I see it gives even `services` and `rdp-tcp` sessions... but I don't want to stop any service...

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

This solution is based on the previous answer but this one will close all sessions (even disconnected sessions).  Unfortunately, the text format of each line returned by the 'query session' command can be difficult to parse.  As you can see in the next screenshot, the username may be empty and in this example, if you use tokens=3, you will get the username instead of the ID for the user compil.

[image]

The problem is that you cant logoff a disconnected user with his username.  To circumvent this problem, we use 2 for loops to get the session name and id (depending on the line format), and then we keep only the numeric values to send the logoff command and logoff also the disconnected sessions.

```
@echo off

for /f "skip=2 tokens=2,3 delims= " %%a in ('query session') DO (
    echo %%a|findstr /xr "[1-9][0-9]* 0" >nul && (
      logoff %%a 
    )

    echo %%b|findstr /xr "[1-9][0-9]* 0" >nul && (
      logoff %%b 
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The page you linked has the correct answer. Except that in Windows 2012 / 10 you should use `skip=2` instead of 1. This way you will skip the 'services' line.
So your batch file will look like this:

```
query session >session.txt
for /f "skip=2 tokens=3," %%i in (session.txt) DO logoff %%i
del session.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

We use this to log off all rdp sessions with the exception of the administrator. Could be tweaked as needed.

@echo off
:: Log off Active Users
query session | findstr "rdp, Active" | findstr /V "dministrator" >sessionActive.txt
for /f "tokens=3" %%i in (sessionActive.txt) DO logoff %%i
del sessionActive.txt

:: Log off Disconnected Users
query session | findstr "Disc" | findstr /V "dministrator, services" >sessionDisc.txt
for /f "tokens=2" %%i in (sessionDisc.txt) DO logoff %%i
del sessionDisc.txt

Answer (score 0):

Note: "file.txt" contain computer name for each line.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ("*\file.txt") do (
    psexec \\%%i -u domain\user -p password logoff console
)
```

Before using this code, you must download PsTools by this link:

> https://download.sysinternals.com/files/PSTools.zip
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/vi-vn/sysinternals/downloads/psexec

Then extract PsTools archive => Copy all file => Paste to "*:\Windows\System32" => Installation Complete

Answer (score 0):

use eol=> to skip active user

```
@echo off

query session > session.txt
::quser > session.txt

for /f "skip=2 eol=> tokens=2,3 delims= " %%G in (session.txt) DO (
    echo %%G|findstr /xr "[1-9][0-9]* 0" >nul && (
      logoff %%G & echo logoff disconnect user %%G
    )

    echo %%H|findstr /xr "[1-9][0-9]* 0" >nul && (
      logoff %%H & echo logoff active user %%H
    )
)

del session.txt
```